# What is the meaning of !#:* !#:1- in a bash command?

Tags: linux, bash

In the following Bash command, what is the meaning of: `!#:*  !#:1`

```
echo "This is a sentence." !#:* !#:1- >text3
```

Comment: http://ss64.com/bash/bang.html

Comment: Is something that's only usable in interactive mode really a programming question? I tend to think that most of the calls for bash questions to be migrated to SuperUser tend to be out-of-line, but this is a case where the thing being asked about is only usable outside of scripts, making it completely useless for programming.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Personally, I would go with: http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I apologize if my question was not interesting or important for you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's using [bash's history substitution mechanism.](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/History-Interaction.html)

Specifically, `!#` refers to the current line (up to but not including the location of the `!#` itself). `!#:*` is the part of that line after the command name (so, in this case, `"This is a sentence."`).  `!#:1-` is the same as `!#:*` except that it omits the last word (so it doesn't include the second copy of `"This is a sentence"` that we just added via the `!#:*`).

The end result is a line with three copies of `This is a sentence.` echoed into a file named `text3`.

Answer (score 6):

The output from:

```
echo "hello" !#
```

is equivalent to the output from:

```
echo "hello" echo "hello"
```

which is:

```
hello echo hello
```

`!#` means substitute previous string before `!#` again to current line (shortcut to avoid writing again)

```
     0th    1st     2nd      3rd
-------- ------- ------ --------
    echo "hello"   echo  "hello"
-------- ------- ------  -------
```

`!#:0`  means substitute value in 0th col

`!#:1`  means substitute value in 1st col

Example

```
echo "hello" !#:1
```

The output from that is the same as the output from:

```
echo "hello" "hello"
```

which is:

```
hello hello
```

`!#:1` is replaced by string in 1st column — `"hello"`

```
echo "hello" !#:0
```

produces the same output as:

```
echo "hello" echo
```

which is:

```
hello echo
```

`!#:0` is replaced by string in 0th column — `echo`

Comment: This doesn't explain that `:*` means "everything after column 0 (starting with column 1)" while `:1-` means "everything starting with column 1 but not including the last column".

Comment: Here's a useful reference link: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Designators.html